How to model a multi category item for effective searching?
an item has a list of categories, what is an good way to model such that search can done in an efficient and effective manner?
For example, Cake could be in categories [Baking, Dessert], Ice cream sandwich is also in [Baking, Dessert]
I want to search for all items with Baking and Dessert, would I want to create a relational or document based database to store and manage this data, if I want to focus on search performance?

What is the 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question? (The tilte question isn't the body question.) PS How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? [ask] [Help]

This is way too vague & general & unresearched. PS "good" "efficient" "effective" "performance" These don't mean anything in particular & especially not without a particular DB paradigm & a particular design & a particular DBMS & further details, which the latter are unforturnately chaotically dependent on. Strategy for “Which is better” questions Q&A is not a good format to learn from scratch. Dozens of (good) (and bad) published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying are online free in pdf & html.

Just looking for some general direction, what would be a good text to refer to?

A relational database would probably be faster.  You could create the same project on multiple databases and publish the results.
A category has one or more items.  An item can be in one or more categories.
In a relational database, you create an item table, a category table, and a junction table to link them together.
Item
----
Item ID
Item Name
...

Catgeory
--------
Category ID
Category Name
...

CategoryItem
------------
Category ID
Item ID
...

Category ID and Item ID is the primary key of the CategoryItem table.  Item ID and Category ID is a unique index.
A sample SQL query might look like:
SELECT Item Name
FROM Category, Item, CategoryItem
WHERE Category Name = 'Dessert'
AND   Category.Category ID = CategoryItem.Category ID
AND   CategoryItem.Item ID = Item.Item ID

